# How to add values to list based on value in pd.DataFrame in corresponding row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe. Amongst the values, I have a 'score' (`int`) column and a 'time_window' (`str`).

I want to append the values under 'score' to a list based on the value under 'time_window'.
I've tried the following `for` loop:

```
avg_04 = []
    
for score in topics_data:
        if topics_data['time_window'] == '0h-4h':
            avg_04.append(topics_data['score'])
```

But i get the following error: `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` and I have no idea what that means.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the dataframe:

```
topics_data[topics_data['time_window'] == '0h-4h']['score'].to_list()
```